# how to prompt to save pdf rather than opening it with fpdf

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I have php code that saves the data in a form to pdf. However right now, its simply opening the data in pdf rather than prompting me to save it as pdf. How can I do that? 
My code is as follows:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{

$f_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$l_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

require("fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",16);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,"welcome {$f_name}",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Name :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$l_name",1,0);

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"gender :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$gender",1,1);

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Mobile :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$mobile",1,1);

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Email :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$email",1,1);


$pdf->Output("D", "filename.pdf");

}

?>
```

Comment: Whether the browser prompts to save or opens the file depends on the browser configuration.  That is up to each user, and you cannot control that from the server side.

Comment: Did you use this to save PDF $filename="path/example.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');

Comment: no , I haven't , how should I edit my code above to do that?

Comment: Just use that $filename="path/example.pdf"; $pdf->Output($filename,'F');  line instead of $pdf->Output();

Comment: i added the exact lines but it still shows up in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPDF's output() method takes two parameters which determine how to output the document. In the version of FPDF I have, they are the opposite way around to [the documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm), so you might want to try both:

```
$pdf->Output("filename.pdf", "D");
```

(which worked for me) and:

```
$pdf->Output("D", "filename.pdf");
```

(which is as per the documentation).

"D" means "send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name" whereas the default is "I" which means "send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available."

Comment: I have edited my code above, it still shows up in the browser

Comment: Ah. I'm afraid it worked for me (although I had to reverse the order of the parameters). Have you tried different browsers since as @Jim Garrison suggests your browser might be configured to open all PDFs inline?

Comment: It works now, I was saving it in wrong file! Thanks!